# How to only sum up values based, when 2 criterias meet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I would like to sum up values in my panda datagram based on the values of two columns. (Python 3.x)

I already tried to use the groupby functions and similar approaches, but as I am relatively new to the topic I need some help.

This is the an example of the data I work with:

```
Date         |   ID   | Count
2019-01-01   | 300020 | 1
2019-01-01   | 300020 | 1
2019-01-01   | 300020 | 1
2019-02-01   | 660020 | 1
2019-02-01   | 300020 | 1
2019-03-01   | 760020 | 1
2019-03-01   | 300020 | 1
2019-03-01   | 300020 | 1
2019-03-01   | 760020 | 1
```

And the end result should be:

```
Date         |   ID   | Count
2019-01-01   | 300020 | 3
2019-02-01   | 660020 | 1
2019-02-01   | 300020 | 1
2019-03-01   | 760020 | 2
2019-03-01   | 300020 | 2
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This is more like `groupby`

```
yourdf=df.groupby(['Date','ID'],sort=False, as_index=False)['Count'].sum()
```

Comment: instead of `yourdf`, you can use `df['name_of_newColumn']` to get the values in a new column in the same dataframe